# How specify the number of datalist's rows to be shown in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

For the function of saving search terms, search keywords are stored in localStorage and shown through the datalist.
But this shows too much data.
So I want to show up to 5 rows of data.
To limit the number of search terms that are stored.
I don't think I'm using the autocomplete function properly, so I need another way.

```
<datalist id="searchHistory">
 {
  keywords.map((item, index) => {
  return <option key={index} value={item.text}/>
  })
 }
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) as shown below to only render first 5 items.

```
<datalist id="searchHistory">
 {
  keywords.slice(0, 5).map((item, index) => {
    return <option key={index} value={item.text}/>
  })
 }
</datalist>
```